# Haxe: Function argument that matches an interface

Tags: interface, arguments, haxe

I have a method (in Haxe) that needs to accept any object that has a 'width' and 'height' property. I'm assuming that I can do that somehow with an Interface, but for my purposes the object that is passed in does not need to implement the interface, it just needs to be *any* object with a width and height property.

This does not work, as the object you pass in needs to implement interface:

```
Interface IWidthAndHeight{
    public var width : Float;
    public var height : Float;
}

Class Main{

    var o : IWidthAndHeight;

    public function setObject( o : IWidthAndHeight ){
        this.o = o;
    }

}
```

Currently I am using Dynamic, and manually cheking that the properties exist, but is there a smarter way?  Current method:

```
Class Main{

    var o : Dynamic;

    public function setObject( o : Dynamic ){
        if (propertiesExist(o,['width','height'])){
            this.o = o;
        }
    }

    // Note: propertiesExist is my own method. Just assume it works :)
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [anonymous structures](https://haxe.org/manual/types-anonymous-structure.html) here:

```
typedef WidthAndHeight = {
    width:Float,
    height:Float
}
class Main {
    var o:WidthAndHeight;
    public function setObject(o:WidthAndHeight) {
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

This is just alternative to `var o:{width:Float, height:Float};` with `typedef`.
Any class or structure in `setObject` argument will be checked for these fields in compile time, this is called [structural subtyping](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-structural-subtyping.html).